# History of Municipal Bonds

Tags: reference-request, bonds, history

Does anyone have a good book on the **history of Muni Bonds** that focuses on the reasons why they grew in popularity, adoption, and gov policy souring them.

**Background on why I need this info**

I am writing a paper for my college history class, titled when wall street met main street. We are allowed to self select a topic and I chose to focus on the change in  the bond markets and that relationship with the public.

What I think could be a great topic is the rise **lease revenue bonds** for funding prisons, and how this has played out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend the following books on municipal finance, with a strong focus on municipal bonds:

1. [Encyclopedia of Municipal Bonds](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20814015-encyclopedia-of-municipal-bonds) (Joe Mysak), despite the name a small book with quick overviews of almost all major topics in municipal finance.
2. [The Handbook of Municipal Bonds](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4195886-the-handbook-of-municipal-bonds) (various authors, a collection of essays), a more detailed and technical volume to build on after reading Mysaks' shorter encyclopedia.
3. [The Fundamentals of Municipal Bonds](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2048821.The_Fundamentals_of_Municipal_Bonds?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=2yNwm5WxYF&rank=1) ([MSRB](http://www.msrb.org/)), a short technical volume on the municipal bond market. Filled with useful charts and statistics.

For color on the evolution of the municipal market, through the lens of major municipal defaults, I recommend:

1. [Detroit Resurrected: To Bankruptcy and Back](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/32191746-detroit-resurrected?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=u4JguZmIcK&rank=1).
2. [Fear City: New York's Fiscal Crisis and the Rise of Austerity Politics](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26792268-fear-city?from_search=true&qid=qOXUG23dh0&rank=4). I preferred the Detroit one if you are only going to read one.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great resources

Answer (score 2):

[The Guidebook to Municipal Bonds: The History, the Industry, the Mechanics](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4442632-the-guide-to-municipal-bonds) (1991) by George J. Malvin

The Tax Policy Center Briefing Book on [The State of State (and Local) Tax Policy](https://www.taxpolicycenter.org/briefing-book/what-are-municipal-bonds-and-how-are-they-used) might be a good place to call.